# Vmware player Ubuntu guest i3wm doesn't recognize multiple monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, vmware, i3-wm

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine on my vmware player.
I am running kernel version 3.19.0.31 since later versions did not work with vmware tools (no auto-resolution for full screen, no multiple monitors).

When I run a Unity session and I "Cycle multiple monitors", everything works as expected. Windows snap to the edges of each screen, the dash opens on the screen with focus, etc. However, in the settings GUI, only one screen is displayed. A screen with a wide resolution (covering both physical screens).

When I run an i3wm session and "Cycle multiple monitors", the same thing happens. 2 screens become one large screen. However, i3wm doesn't magically treat them like two screens as Unity did.

When I run `xrandr`, I see only one screen with a wide resolution of 3360*1050. Same for both Unity and i3wm

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3360 x 1050, maximum 5280 x 1920
default connected 3360x1050+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   800x600       60.00    85.00    75.00    72.00    56.00     0.00  
   2048x1536     85.00    75.00    60.00     0.00  
   1920x1440     85.00    75.00    60.00     0.00  
   1856x1392     75.00    60.00  
   1792x1344     75.00    60.00  
   1600x1200     85.00    75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00     0.00  
   1680x1050     85.00    75.00    70.00    60.00     0.00  
   1400x1050     85.00    75.00    70.00    60.00     0.00  
   1280x1024     85.00    75.00    60.00     0.00  
   1440x900      60.00     0.00  
   1280x960      85.00    60.00     0.00  
   1360x768      60.00  
   1152x864     100.00    85.00    75.00    70.00    60.00     0.00  
   1024x768      85.00    75.00    70.00    60.00     0.00  
   832x624       75.00  
   640x480       85.00    75.00    73.00    60.00     0.00  
   720x400       85.00  
   640x400       85.00     0.00  
   640x350       85.00  
   320x240        0.00  
   400x300        0.00  
   512x384        0.00  
   2560x1920      0.00  
   854x480        0.00  
   1280x720       0.00  
   1366x768       0.00  
   1920x1080      0.00  
   1280x800       0.00  
   1920x1200      0.00  
   2560x1600      0.00  
   720x480        0.00  
   720x576        0.00  
   320x200        0.00  
   800x480        0.00  
   1280x768       0.00  
   5280x1920      0.00  
   3360x1050      0.00*
```

Worth mentioning is that initially, I could not cycle the monitors with i3wm, but I used a fix found online that involves adding `exec --no-startup-id vmware-user` to my `~/.i3/config`

**UPDATE**

I tried running with the latest kernel 4.4.0-34-generic, which did not work with Unity. It seems to work perfectly with i3. xrandr shows both displays and the screens are handled correctly. Not sure why this needs to be so confusing, but at least now it works :)

Comment: Does `xrandr` also show only a single screen, when run from unity? BTW: It should be `exec --no-startup-id vmware-user`, else *i3's* configuration parser will take `--no-startup-id` as argument to the `vmware-user` command and not as option to the `exec` configuration directive.

Comment: huh. Interestingly, Unity actually shows the same xrandr output. And the settings GUI also only displays one screen with wide resolution. However, it does behave like two screens, i.e. the windows snap to the edges of the two screens, the dash opens on the screen with focus, etc. I'll update the question